# UTF-8 Fancytext to alphanumerical in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, utf-8

I have an HTML username input where UTF-8 is accepted. Users can add "fancytext" to their names, such as (, `Ⓐ`, , `ᗩ`, etc.) to make it more stylistic. However, I would like to do some parsing with their names client-side (for example, searching and finding words in the name).

Is there a way, in JavaScript, where I can convert fancy text into their alphanumerical values without a large dataset? So `""`, `"Ⓐ"`, `""`, `"ᗩ"` all result in `"a"`? (Unconvertable values return false or something).

Some of my tests show that there is a pattern with the characters and toCharCode.

```
var str = "ⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼＡＢＣＤＥＦＧ";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    console.log(str.charCodeAt(i))

// Prints 9398 9399 9400 9401 9402 9403 9404 65313 65314 65315 65316 65317 65318 65319
```

However, I am unable to confirm whether this applies to all because I cannot get the charCodes of multi-byte characters.

```
var encodings = "ⒶⓏⓐⓩ乙ΛẒαzＡＺａｚᗩƵΔŽคzαzάžÃŻĄȤℤᵃᶻɐz"

for (var i = 0; i < encodings.length; i++) {

    console.log(encodings.charCodeAt(i), encodings.charAt(i))
}
/*
    Prints:

    55356 � 56688 � 55356 � 56713 � 9398 Ⓐ 9423 Ⓩ 9424 ⓐ 9449 ⓩ 55296 � 57088 � 20057 乙 923 Λ 7826 Ẓ 945 α 122 z 65313 Ａ 65338 Ｚ 65345 ａ 65370 ｚ 5609 ᗩ 437 Ƶ 916 Δ 381 Ž 3588 ค 122 z 945 α 122 z 940 ά 382 ž 195 Ã 379 Ż 260 Ą 548 Ȥ 55349 � 56606 � 55349 � 56631 � 55349 � 56554 � 55349 � 56579 � 55349 � 56502 � 55349 � 56527 � 55349 � 56528 � 55349 � 56553 � 55349 � 56320 � 55349 � 56345 � 55349 � 56346 � 55349 � 56371 � 55349 � 56632 � 8484 ℤ 55349 � 56658 � 55349 � 56683 � 7491 ᵃ 7611 ᶻ 592 ɐ 122 z
*/
```

If multi-byte characters can be read properly though, this is a possible solution:

```
function getAlphanumericalFromFancytext(char) {
    var encodings = "ⒶⓏⓐⓩ乙ΛẒαzＡＺａｚᗩƵΔŽคzαzάžÃŻĄȤℤᵃᶻɐz"

    var code = getCharCodeMultibyte(char, 0); // getCharCodeMultibyte(string, index) gets charCode for utf8 multibyte characters

    for (var i = 0; i < encodings.length; i += 2) {
        var startCode = getCharCodeMultibyte(encodings, i),
            endCode = getCharCodeMultibyte(encodings, i+1);

        if (code >= startCode && code <= endCode) {
            return String.fromCharCode(code - startCode + "a".charCodeAt(0));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

I figured out a way to read multi-byte characters from the Mozilla documentation. But it still returns incorrect results.

```
function getCharCodeMultibyte(str, idx) {
    // For example, fixedCharCodeAt('\uD800\uDC00', 0); // 65536
    // For example, fixedCharCodeAt('\uD800\uDC00', 1); // false
    idx = idx || 0;
    var code = str.charCodeAt(idx);
    var hi, low;

    // High surrogate (could change last hex to 0xDB7F
    // to treat high private surrogates
    // as single characters)
    if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) {
        hi = code;
        low = str.charCodeAt(idx + 1);
        if (isNaN(low)) {
            throw 'High surrogate not followed by ' +
                'low surrogate in fixedCharCodeAt()';
        }
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) +
                (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) { // Low surrogate
        // We return false to allow loops to skip
        // this iteration since should have already handled
        // high surrogate above in the previous iteration
        return false;
        // hi = str.charCodeAt(idx - 1);
        // low = code;
        // return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) +
        //   (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    return code;
}

function getAlphanumericalFromFancytext(char) {
    var encodings = ["", "", "Ⓐ", "Ⓩ", "ⓐ", "ⓩ", "", "乙", "Λ", "Ẓ", "α", "z", "Ａ", "Ｚ", "ａ", "ｚ", "ᗩ", "Ƶ", "Δ", "Ž", "ค", "z", "α", "z", "ά", "ž", "Ã", "Ż", "Ą", "Ȥ", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "ℤ", "", "", "ᵃ", "ᶻ", "ɐ", "z"]

    var code = getCharCodeMultibyte(char, 0); // getCharCodeMultibyte(string, index) gets charCode for utf8 multibyte characters

    for (var i = 0; i < encodings.length; i += 2) {
        var startCode = getCharCodeMultibyte(encodings[i], 0),
            endCode = getCharCodeMultibyte(encodings[i + 1], 0);

        if (code >= startCode && code <= endCode) {
            //console.log(i + "|" + String.fromCharCode(code - startCode + "a".charCodeAt(0)) + "|" + code + "|" + startCode + "|" + endCode)
            return String.fromCharCode(code - startCode + "a".charCodeAt(0));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var text = ["", "Ⓔ", "ᒪ", "ᒪ", ""]
var output = [];

text.forEach((char) => {
    output.push(getAlphanumericalFromFancytext(char))
})
console.log(output.join("")) // Returns heᅰᅰo. "Λ", "Ẓ" is where it messes up.
```

Comment: Maybe an idea might be to get the charCode with `charCodeAt` and do some math. So if it is between a min and a max bound, it will subtract by the min and do `toCharCode` to get the value. But this only works if the ordering of the letters is the same.

Comment: You could make a separate script that will filter out all of these and convert them manually according to your qualitative assessment. But only do this if there really isn't an appropriate math to do so like your comment above. I doubt there is

Comment: Actually, I just ran a little test and found out that they do follow some order/math.

`var str = "ⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼＡＢＣＤＥＦＧ";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) console.log(str.charCodeAt(i))` prints `9398 9399 9400 9401 9402 9403 9404 65313 65314 65315 65316 65317 65318 65319`. But I am not sure if the same applies for everything.

Comment: Lemme do some concept test for you based on that manual ordering you made and ill post it as an answer. Can u give me one complete set of those characters from A-Z. Too lazy to google

Comment: @Andrew *"But I am not sure if the same applies for everything"* The only way to know is by trying/testing it for yourself.... It would appear you have come for help before trying your own attempts. I would suggest you try all you think/know and exhaust your resources before submitting this sort of question.

Comment: @NewToJS. I have actually tested all that I know. I think there is a pattern, but my tests cant really show it for all. For example, I cannot test if the order follows for `` or `ⒶⓏ` because they are multi-byte characters and I dont know how to do "toCharCode" with them.

Comment: If you have tried something and testing a pattern I would suggest you add the source code of that into your question. This could lead to more work on your method or comments to help understand problems you might have using the current source code.

Comment: Sure! I will edit it right away.

Comment: @Andrew much appreciated. Maybe your current attempt can be worked on to give a solution and help others or the current attempt can lead to relevant comments of why it isn't going to work as expected.

Comment: @NewToJS Also included a possible solution if multiByte characters can be read

Comment: I think I found a way to get char codes of multi-byte characters. Scroll down the page here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt.

But I cant figure out how to use it in a loop. Because `.length` becomes inaccurate. Maybe instead I should use an array.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the idea based on the structure that you have gave us, I was able to construct this short helper object to convert fancy text to normal alphabets based on an infinite number of datasets. Provided that the characters to be compared are always 1:1

Just use it like this

```
const ftp = new FancyTextParser();
const parsed = ftp.parse("คⓑⓒd");
console.log(parsed); //abcd
```

You would have to manually add your own character sets on `this.charset` object making sure that the character positions of each dataset matches the `base` character set.

The limitation of the current code is that I cannot take into consideration letter casing, as my base characters could only either be lower or upper.

```js
    function FancyTextParser() {
        const _this = this;

        this.charset = {
            base: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
            charset1: "ⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⓩ",
            charset2: "ค",
        }

        this.enumerate = function () {
            for (let c in this.charset) {
                 this.charset[c] = this.charset[c].split("");
            }
        }

        this.parse = function (input) {
            input = input.split("");

            let output = "";

            input.forEach(function (schar) {
                for (let d in _this.charset) {
                    const idx = _this.charset[d].findIndex(function (a) { return a == schar });
                    if (idx != -1) output += _this.charset.base[idx];
                }
            });

            return output;
        }

        this.enumerate();
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        window.ftp = new FancyTextParser();
        const parsed = ftp.parse("คⓑⓒd");
        console.log(parsed);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-16">
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmm. But I am trying not use use an `a` to `z` dataset. Rather, only the `a` and `z`. Maybe my failed solution above can help?

Comment: You can modify the helper to get only the A and Z and then automatically fill the datasets based on the `charCode` ranges. You should be able to integrate your algorithm with this. I already handled the conversion for you, which is the core goal of this thread and your post title

Comment: The current state of this helper I made uses static datasets. You can modify it to generate datasets automatically based on the range of A and Z -- which you seem to find out yourself that each character set follows an incremental pattern, it will be a piece of cake

Comment: Understand. I was looking for something that has all the datasets filled in, because I do not know how to do that (Especially multi-byte). I also found that some do not follow a specific pattern, but I dont know which ones. Maybe I should just get everything from http://fancytext.blogspot.com/?

Comment: Adding in all the datasets manually isn't really a problem tbh, and at the bottom of it all you still have to manually add the A and Z anyway, so what's the point; scratching our heads to make it generate characters automatically is just wasting time imo. You don't really need to add the character sets programmatically, your goal here is to convert fancy text to normal alphabets using some sort of conversion algorithm. Now that some characters do not follow a charCode specific pattern, your way becomes far-fetched